# Get real coordinates of Point (or any other constructed object)

Tags: geogebra

In GeoGebra, you can easily construct scenes with the GUI and the tools available in the Graphics view. I now have two functions and created some objects around them using that tools (Their intersection point, a circle tangent to both etc.). The whole depends on 5 parameters I defined as sliders for testing.

Now I want to know the coordinates of the point. It is defined as `Intersect[l, h]` which doesn't help me. I can access its coordinates too `(0.8, 3.98)` but I want to know how to calculate them depending on the parameters. (I'd expect it to be something like `(3a, 7+b-2a)`). I know GeoGebra can do this because it *must* have done it internally to be able to draw the whole image. But I don't know how to access this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the *current* position of a Point `P` you can use the [`x` and `y` commands](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Tips:Point_Coordinates). These will update whenever the position of `P` changes so that you don't have to recalculate where the point should be by hand.

Comment: This is exactly what I _didn't_ ask for in the question.